# MYSQL : trigger (NOW.'#Column')

Tags: mysql, comments, database-trigger

I have a problem in mySQL, when i'm trying to access into '#employeeId' colomn
from NOW it fails
NEW.`#employe`

Comment: The question is unclear, could you provide a little more detail about what you are trying to accomplish, maybe the design/sql query you have so far

Answer (score 0):

If you have a literal `#` character in your column name, you should know that `#` is a comment leader character in MySQL.

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comments.html

You can use this special character if you delimit your column name in back-ticks:

```
NEW.`#employeeId`
```